# Problema de building de app ionic

Tags: ionic

Sou um desenvolvedor novato de apps, começando com Ionic e sou usuário do Debian.

depois de pronto o app e dentro do diretório do mesmo, abro um terminal e rodo o comando `ionic cordova build --release android`, porém recebo o retorno abaixo, ele reclama que o caminho para o sdk, jdk e gradle estão errados, mas estes caminhos levam para os aquivos.

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para resolver este problema.

> ~/ionic/compareProduct$ ionic cordova build --release android Running
>   app-scripts build: --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser
>
> [22:38:25]  build dev started ...  [22:38:25]  clean started ... 
>   [22:38:25]  clean finished in 4 ms  [22:38:25]  copy started ... 
>   [22:38:25]  transpile started ...  [22:38:29]  transpile finished in
>   3.78 s  [22:38:29]  preprocess started ...  [22:38:29]  deeplinks started ...  [22:38:29]  deeplinks finished in 21 ms  [22:38:29] 
>   preprocess finished in 23 ms  [22:38:29]  webpack started ... 
>   [22:38:29]  copy finished in 4.07 s  [22:38:42]  webpack finished in
>   12.63 s  [22:38:42]  sass started ...  [22:38:44]  sass finished in 1.73 s  [22:38:44]  postprocess started ...  [22:38:44]  postprocess finished in 8 ms  [22:38:44]  lint started ...  [22:38:44]  build dev
>   finished in 18.24 s
>
> > cordova build android --release ✖ Running command - failed!
>
> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>            [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1):
>
> ANDROID_HOME=/home/willer/sdk-tools-linux-3859397
>   JAVA_HOME=/home/willer/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java
>
> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /home/willer/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
>
> Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certamente o problema é na definição da Variável de ambiente JAVA_HOME
[Instalação do Ionic no Windows (Explica sobre o JAVA_HOME)](http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/tutorial-de-configuracao-do-ambiente-ionic-android-no-windows/)

Se caso ultilizar Linux, é só utilizar o

```
export JAVA_HOME={YOUR_PATH}
```

Comment: sim vc tem razão, abei de perceber isso obrigado! mas o legal é por dentro de um arquivo script que é carregado com o sistema.